# Unable to build Swing app in Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel, osx-yosemite

I am trying to build Swing Java app on Mac OS X (Yosemite) v.10.10 (14A379b).
So far I have tried with different JDKs like, 1.7.0_60, 1.7.0_67, 1.8.0_20 etc...

However I get this error each time:

```
compile_components:
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:478: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:483: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:488: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:493: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:498: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:503: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:508: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:513: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:518: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:523: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:528: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:538: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:543: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:548: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:553: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:558: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:563: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:568: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:573: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:578: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:583: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:588: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:593: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:598: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:603: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:608: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:613: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:618: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:623: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:628: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:633: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:638: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:643: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:648: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:653: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:658: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:663: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:668: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:673: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:678: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:683: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:688: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:693: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:698: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:703: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:708: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:713: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:718: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:723: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:728: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

compile:

compile_mac_lnf:
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:468: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build/classes
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:10: error: package apple.laf does not exist
    [javac] import apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel extends AquaLookAndFeel {
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol: class AquaLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:82: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:87: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:92: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:97: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:102: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.initClassDefaults(table);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.initComponentDefaults(table);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:138: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     getClass().getResource(EXPAND_ICON_FILE_NAME)));
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     getClass().getResource(CONTRACT_ICON_FILE_NAME)));
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("ButtomPanel.minIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("ButtomPanel.fullIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("ButtomPanel.restoreIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("SideMenu.expandIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("SideMenu.collapseIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:177: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("SideMenu.pinIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] /Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/src/java/main/com/topcoder/umltool/deploy/UMLToolMacLookAndFeel.java:223: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             UIManager.put("SideMenu.pinIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass()
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getClass()
    [javac]   location: class UMLToolMacLookAndFeel
    [javac] 18 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:183: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/ZeKoU/Development/topcoder-UML-Tool/build.xml:468: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

So my obvious problem is "import apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel;"

However, I can't figure out from where it should be available if not inside JDK installation?
P.S. I am Mac beginner.

Kind Regards

Comment: The message at https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2004/Oct/msg00529.html says: "The class apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel can be found inside:
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Classes/laf.jar".  Can you find this class in that location (or the equivalent for a more recent Java version).